# VMWare on Intel i7-2600[S/K]: VM processor configuration for maximum performance

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, vmware-workstation, cpu-architecture

I have an Intel i7-2600K-processor, which has 4 cores but runs 8 thread because of Hyperthreading. I want to run a Ubuntu-VM with maximum performance under VMWare 8 (host system is Windows 7, and is doing nothing more than running VMWare), so I'm looking for the best CPU setting for that VM. Now how many cores do I configure, 4 or 8?

config 1:
Number of processors: 1
Number of cores per processor: 4

config 2:
Number of processors: 1
Number of cores per processor: 8

Comment: oops, these configs are pretty wrong. of course its only one cpu, so the question is more like if i can set 1cpu/4cores or 1cpu/8cores.

Comment: See my answer, it is still valid. Oh, and I would edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: changed the question accordingly

Comment: Oh, why don't you actually just run Ubuntu natively if you dont use your win7 for anything else? That would eliminate the overhead of running win7 and VM.

Comment: Because I have some hardware driver issues on Linux, since some drivers are not available or implemented badly. Also the power management (control fan speed etc.) is bad or really hard to implement on Linux. So I want Windows to handle all the Hardware drivers stuff and let Linux access the hardware through VMWare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you using

- Number of processors: 1
- Number of cores per processor: 8

You can count your threads as physical cores, just like the Taskmanager does.
VM should be able to use your full resources then.